# Grunt php livereload not work

Tags: javascript, php, gruntjs, livereload, grunt-contrib-watch

i've a grunt script that run a php server, i've configured grunt to watch php files and livereload them.
When i change a php file (and other kind of file inside my project) grunt log:

```
File "application/views/welcome_message.php" changed.
Completed in 0.000s at Tue Feb 25 2014 11:28:45 GMT+0100 (CET) - Waiting...
```

but not reload file!

This is my Grunt.js

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function (grunt) {

    // Load grunt tasks automatically
    require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

    // Time how long tasks take. Can help when optimizing build times
    require('time-grunt')(grunt);

/**
 * ===================================================
 * Project configuration.
 * ===================================================
 */
    grunt.initConfig({

        // Project settings
        yeoman: {
            // Configurable paths
            app: 'assets',
            ci: 'application',
            local: '.',
            dist: 'dist'
        },

        // Watches files for changes and runs tasks based on the changed files
        watch: {
            js: {
                files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'], // La proprietà 'files' specifica quale file il task watch dovrebbe monitorare
                tasks: ['jshint'], // La proprietà 'tasks' definisce un'array di grunt task che dovrebbero essere eseguiti quando cambia uno dei file osservato
                options: {
                    livereload: '<%= php.options.livereload %>'
                }
            },
            jstest: {
                files: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.js'],
                tasks: ['test:watch']
            },
            gruntfile: {
                files: ['Gruntfile.js']
            },
            compass: {
                files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}'],
                tasks: ['compass:server', 'autoprefixer']
            },
            styles: {
                files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
                tasks: ['newer:copy:styles', 'autoprefixer'],
                options: {
                    livereload: '<%= php.options.livereload %>'
                }
            },
            livereload: {
                options: {
                    livereload: '<%= php.options.livereload %>'
                },
                files: [
                    '<%= yeoman.app %>/{,*/}*.html',
                    '<%= yeoman.ci %>/{,*/}*.php',
                    '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
                    '<%= yeoman.app %>/images/{,*/}*.{gif,jpeg,jpg,png,svg,webp}'
                ]
            }
        },

        // Grunt PHP server settings
        php: {
            options: {
                port: 5555,
                livereload: 35730,
                // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside
                hostname: 'localhost'
            },
            start: {
                options: {
                    open: true,
                    // keepalive: true,
                    base: '<%= yeoman.local %>'
                }
            }
        },

        // The actual grunt server settings
        connect: {
            options: {
                port: 9000,
                livereload: 35730,
                // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside
                hostname: 'localhost'
            },
            start: {
                options: {
                    open: true,
                    base: [
                        '.tmp',
                        '<%= yeoman.app %>'
                    ]
                }
            },
            test: {
                options: {
                    port: 9001,
                    base: [
                        '.tmp',
                        'test',
                        '<%= yeoman.app %>'
                    ]
                }
            },
            dist: {
                options: {
                    open: true,
                    base: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
                    livereload: false
                }
            }
        },

        // Empties folders to start fresh
        clean: {
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    dot: true,
                    src: [
                        '.tmp',
                        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/*',
                        '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/.git*'
                    ]
                }]
            },
            server: '.tmp'
        },

        // Make sure code styles are up to par and there are no obvious mistakes
        // Controllo correttezza js
        jshint: {
            options: {
                jshintrc: '.jshintrc',
                reporter: require('jshint-stylish')
            },
            all: [
                'Gruntfile.js',
                '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
                '!<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/vendor/*',
                'test/spec/{,*/}*.js'
            ]
        },

        // Compiles Sass to CSS and generates necessary files if requested
        compass: {
            options: {
                sassDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
                cssDir: '.tmp/styles',
                generatedImagesDir: '.tmp/images/generated',
                imagesDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
                javascriptsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts',
                fontsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/fonts',
                importPath: '<%= yeoman.app %>/bower_components',
                httpImagesPath: '/images',
                httpGeneratedImagesPath: '/images/generated',
                httpFontsPath: '/fonts',
                relativeAssets: false,
                assetCacheBuster: false
            },
            dist: {
                options: {
                    generatedImagesDir: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/generated',
                    outputStyle: 'compressed'
                }
            },
            server: {
                options: {
                    debugInfo: true
                }
            }
        },

        // Add vendor prefixed styles
        autoprefixer: {
            options: {
                browsers: ['last 1 version']
            },
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '.tmp/styles/',
                    src: '{,*/}*.css',
                    dest: '.tmp/styles/'
                }]
            }
        },

        // Automatically inject Bower components into the HTML file
        'bower-install': {
            app: {
                html: '<%= yeoman.ci %>/views/welcome_message.php',
                ignorePath: '<%= yeoman.ci %>/'
            }
        },

        // Renames files for browser caching purposes
        rev: {
            dist: {
                files: {
                    src: [
                        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
                        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css',
                        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/{,*/}*.{gif,jpeg,jpg,png,webp}',
                        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/fonts/{,*/}*.*'
                    ]
                }
            }
        },

        // Copies remaining files to places other tasks can use
        copy: {
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    dot: true,
                    cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
                    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
                    src: [
                        '*.{ico,png,txt}',
                        '.htaccess',
                        'images/{,*/}*.webp',
                        '{,*/}*.html',
                        '{,*/}*.php',
                        'styles/fonts/{,*/}*.*'
                    ]
                }]
            },
            styles: {
                expand: true,
                dot: true,
                cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
                dest: '.tmp/styles/',
                src: '{,*/}*.css'
            }
        },


        // Generates a custom Modernizr build that includes only the tests you
        // reference in your app
        modernizr: {
            devFile: '<%= yeoman.app %>/bower_components/modernizr/modernizr.js',
            outputFile: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/bower_components/modernizr/modernizr.js',
            files: [
                '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
                '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css',
                '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/vendor/*'
            ],
            uglify: true
        },

        // Run some tasks in parallel to speed up build process
        concurrent: {
            server: [
                'compass:server',
                'copy:styles'
            ],
            test: [
                'copy:styles'
            ],
            dist: [
                'compass',
                'copy:styles',
                'imagemin',
                'svgmin'
            ]
        }
    });

/**
 * ===================================================
 * TASK LIST
 * ===================================================
 */

    grunt.registerTask('serve', function (target) {
        if (target === 'dist') {
            return grunt.task.run(['build', 'connect:dist:keepalive']);
        }

        grunt.task.run([
            'clean:server',
            'concurrent:server',
            'autoprefixer',
            'phpwatch'
        ]);
    });

    grunt.registerTask('server', function () {
        grunt.log.warn('The `server` task has been deprecated. Use `grunt serve` to start a server.');
        grunt.task.run(['serve']);
    });

    grunt.registerTask('test', function (target) {
        if (target !== 'watch') {
            grunt.task.run([
                'clean:server',
                'concurrent:test',
                'autoprefixer',
            ]);
        }

        grunt.task.run([
            'connect:test',
            'mocha'
        ]);
    });

    grunt.registerTask('build', [
        'clean:dist',
        'useminPrepare',
        'concurrent:dist',
        'autoprefixer',
        'concat',
        'cssmin',
        'uglify',
        'copy:dist',
        'modernizr',
        'rev',
        'usemin',
        'htmlmin'
    ]);

    grunt.registerTask('default', [
        'newer:jshint',
        'test',
        'build'
    ]);

    grunt.registerTask('phpwatch', ['php:start', 'watch']);

};
```

What's wrong with what I am doing?

Answer (score -1):

Try leaving everything as it is and changing:

```
// Grunt PHP server settings
php: {
    options: {
        port: 5555,
        livereload: 35730,
```

to:

```
// Grunt PHP server settings
php: {
    options: {
        port: 5555,
        livereload: <%= connect.options.livereload %>,
```

That way it's defined only in one spot.

Comment: changing the value of a property is not going to do anything if that property is not supported